# Formulating a Transition matrix for Markov Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am dealing with a medical process which is as follows.

There are 10000 Veterans who are enrolled in this study.

All 10000 have medical condition called onychocryptosis which is a fancy term for ingrown toenails.

### Step 1:

The first line of treatment for such problem is Surgery. All 10,000 Veterans diagnosed with onychocryptosis (ingrown toe nail) are subjected to surgery to remove their ingrown toe nail.

### Step 2:

A subset of these 10000 Veterans develop infection after Surgery and are treated with a 8.5mg Pain reliving gel (8.5Gel)

### Step 3:

A subset of these Veterans still have problems and infection does not subside/does not go away. Even after 8.5mg Pain reliving gel, their condition worsens. So these Vetrans are given 5ml Cannabis Oil.

### Step 4:

A subset of veterans still have problem even after 5ml Cannabis Oil treatment so they are given 10ml Cannabis Oil.

Please note all 10,000 veterans in this study go through Step1 (Surgery). After Step1, some go to Step2 (8.5mg Gel) some are fine and have no problems with their toes. Among patients in Step2, some progress to Step3 (5mg Cannabis Oil) and some are fine after Step2. Among patients in Step3 , some progress to Step4 (10mg Cannabis Oil) some are fine after Step3.

The treatment options are sequential. Nobody starts directly in Step2 or Step3 or Step4. Everybody starts from Step1.

My question is how should I formulate my discrete Markov Transition probability matrix for this process.

Is this TPM below correct. Does it accurately reflect the process I am mentioning above ?? Please advise.

\begin{bmatrix}
* & S & 8.5mgGel & 5mlCoil & 10mlCoil & \\
\hline
S & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
8.5mgGel & 1-p & p & 0 & 0 & \\
5mlCoil & 0 & 1-p & p & 0 & \\
10mlCoil & 0 & 0 & 1-p & p & \\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: I don't see how this will work. What is the state space for your Markov Chain? Your transition matrix seems to indicate $P(X_2 = s|X_1 = 8.5) = 1-p.$ However, the description of your procedure with patients does not seem to envision patients on 8.5mgGel transitioning to Surgery.

Comment: @BruceET, Thanks Bruce, thats what I thought. I knew I am was doing something wrong. This is my state space  $Z = [S, 8.5mgGel, 5mlCoil, 10mlCoil] $

Comment: I think you need 10ml to be an absorbing state, unless there is an extra state to exit the study after getting high on cannabis oil for a while.